# Bootstrap datatable not displaying on other tabs

Tags: datatables

This is the code that I have written with laravel5, basically I'm trying to display various tables separately based on the option from the dropdown chosen, the datatable works for the first table result however does not work for the rest, correct me if I'm wrong but apprently it has something to do with the data from the first call; if the second datatable uses the same function it will see that data has already been fetched and not make the ajax call to retrieve its data. and so you will not receive data to your second(nth) datatable. Been trying to solve this for two days, I believe I'm missing something, someone please helpme in providing a solution. Thank you in advance.

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')

<h1 class="page-header">Reports Archive</h1>     
<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="drop5" href="#" class="btn btn-default  dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
    Zone Options: 
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul id="menu2" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop5">
    <?php $count = 1; ?>
    @foreach ($zones as $zone)
    <li role="presentation" class="{{ $count == 0 ?  'active' : '' }}">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-target="#zone{{ $zone->id }}"> {{ $zone->zone_name }}</a></li>
      <?php $count++; ?>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel">
    <!-- hide the below links-->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="display:none;" role="tablist" id="myTab">
      <?php $count = 1; ?>
      @foreach ($zones as $zone)
      <li role="presentation" class="{{ $count == 0 ?  'active' : '' }}"><a href="#zone{{ $zone->id }}" aria-controls="zone{{ $zone->id }}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{ $zone->zone_name }}</a></li>
      <?php $count++; ?>
      @endforeach
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <?php $count = 1; ?>
      @foreach ($zones as $zone)
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in {{ $count == 0 ?  'active' : '' }}" id="zone{{ $zone->id }}">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2> {{ $zone->zone_name }}  </h2>
          <table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered" id="bootstrap-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="vertical-align:middle">#</th>
                <th>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a id="drop5" href="#" class="btn btn-default  dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                      Parameter Name: 
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="menu2" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop5">
                      @foreach ($zone->parameter as $param)
                      <li role="presentation">
                        <a class="btn btn-link" data-collapse-group="filters" data-target="#{{ $param->id }}" data-toggle="collapse">{{ $param->parameter_name }}</a></li>
                        @endforeach
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">Reading Value</th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">User</th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">Status</th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">Timestamp</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

             @forelse ($parameters as $param)
              <?php $index = 1; ?>
              @if ($param->zone_id == $zone->id)
              <tbody id="{{ $param->id }}" class="collapse">
                @foreach ($readings as $reading)
                @if ($param->id == $reading->parameter_id)
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ $index }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $reading->parameter->parameter_name }} </td>
                  <td>{{ $reading->reading_value }} </td>
                  <td>{{ $reading->user->name }} </td>
                  <td>{{ $reading->parameter->threshold->getStatus($reading->reading_value) }} </td>
                  <td>{{ $reading->created_at }} </td>
                </tr>
                <?php $index++; ?>
                @endif
                @endforeach
                @endif         
                @empty  
                <tr><td  colspan="6"><div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" style = "margin-top: 10px"> Oops! There are no parameters to display here </div></td></tr>
              </tbody>
            </div>
              @endforelse
            </div>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php $count++; ?>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
  @stop

@section('scripts')
<!-- Bootstrap Based Data Table Plugin Script-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bdt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#bootstrap-table').bdt();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script> 

<script>
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

</script>
@stop
```